# How to get a View object that has focus?

Tags: android, android-view, remote-access

How do I get the `View` that currently has focus, not necessarily of my own application?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do it on your own application using an [OnGlobalFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener.html), but, even though I never tried it, I'm fairly certain it won't work outside of you app.